# Difficulty with Latex Exportation

Tags: export, latex

I have a rather big notebook which I would like to export to Latex. Upon doing the naive Save As -> tex file, it seems that TeXStudio is not able to handle the resulting file. It is very laggy, the buffer is overloaded (I get multiple error message on that end if I try to compile it) and the resulting pdf is corrupted. There does not seem to be any Latex error as per se though. I tried unsuccessfully on TeXmaker as well.
How can I overcome this technical difficulty?

Comment: Try selecting a portion of your notebook and right click and select "Copy -> LaTeX".  Paste that into you LaTeX compiler and see what you get.

Comment: Hi. I tried doing that. I does not seem to work. When copying, Mathematica pops a message with multiple error and if I try to paste it into a Latex compiler, nothing happens.